# Calculate difference between two columns, one holding a JSON object and the other holding a JSON array

Tags: json, google-bigquery

Say I have a table like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE sandbox.test(
  id INT64,
  observation JSON,
  prediction JSON
);

INSERT INTO sandbox.test VALUES
(1, 
 JSON """{"temp": {"sensor": "foo", "value": 1}}""", 
 JSON """{"temp": {"source": "alpha", "value": 3}}""");
```

I'd like to calculate the ∆ between the prediction and observation columns, so I do the following:

```
SELECT *, FLOAT64(observation.temp.value) - FLOAT64(prediction.temp.value) AS delta 
FROM sandbox.test
```

This works just fine.

---

Now, say I had an *array* of predictions, like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE sandbox.test(
  id INT64,
  observation JSON,
  prediction JSON
);

INSERT INTO sandbox.test VALUES
(1, 
 JSON """{"temp": {"sensor": "foo", "value": 1}}""", 
 JSON """{"temp": [{"source": "alpha", "value": 3}, {"source": "beta", "value": 1}]}""");
```

I can calculate differences between the observation and each prediction in the array by explicitly referring to array elements:

```
SELECT *, FLOAT64(observation.temp.value) - FLOAT64(prediction.temp[0].value) AS delta_alpha 
FROM sandbox.test
```

but in my specific case there are numerous elements so it's a bit cumbersome to write them all out individually. Is it possible to iterate over *all* elements in the array and calculate the ∆ without having to write them out one by one? It would be ideal if I could then store all of these ∆ values in a JSON object, too.

Comment: *It would be ideal if I could then store all of these ∆ values in a JSON object, too.* --> how the json output look like ?

Comment: @Jaytiger It would look exactly like you predicted below – fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It would be ideal if I could then store all of these ∆ values in a JSON object, too.

You can consider below.

```sql
SELECT *,
       TO_JSON(STRUCT(ARRAY(
         SELECT AS STRUCT p.source,
                FLOAT64(observation.temp.value) - FLOAT64(p.value) AS delta
           FROM UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(prediction.temp)) p
       ) AS temp)) AS delta
  FROM `sandbox.test`;
```

**Query result**

[image]